# Custom Field IF/ELSE PHP

Tags: php, custom-field

Ok so i am trying to use WordPress's custom fields and have them working but now i have some php code i need help with.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ct_text_4dc9e9f74d000', true ); ?>">Go To Store!</a>
```

The above code is what i have for right now. Is there a way to setup a if and else statement so if there is a value in the custom field then show that but else show N/A if there is no value present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
$customhref = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ct_text_4dc9e9f74d000', true );

if ( $customhref ) {
?>
     <a href="<?php echo $customhref; ?>">Go To Store!</a>
<?php
} else {
     echo 'N/A';
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. I have been widening my skills in web development and php is still in the ok need to still learn and research. I was trying to do it way differently. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Chip's answer is great (and earned a +1), but just as an alternative as you are learning PHP, I prefer this style as it takes only a single line in the file that I will use and integrates better with the flow of the HTML.

```
<?php if(get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ct_text_4dc9e9f74d000', true )) : ?>
   <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ct_text_4dc9e9f74d000', true ); ?>">Go To Store!</a>
<?php else : ?>
   N/A
<?php endif; ?>
```

Again, this is just a matter of preference and it might be helpful for you to see other ways to do the same thing.

Comment: thanks for the alternative I did end up using chips and just squashed it down to one line

Comment: you're calling `get_post_meta` twice. You could assign the result in the first if to shorten and optimize code a bit: `if ($x = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'field', TRUE)) { echo $x; } else { }`

Comment: @Geert...well played! Bad form on my part. I was trying too hard to demonstrate the one line approach and forgot the common sense of not running that function twice.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of forcing code onto one line. PHP doesn't care about whitespace, and I like to make my code human-readable - mainly, so that later on, I can follow/remember what code I wrote, and why. :) Mainly a matter of personal preference, I'm sure.

Comment: @Geert - how would your improvement fit this `<?php $custom_field = (string) get_post_meta( $post->ID, "XYZ", true ); echo str_replace(' ', '', $custom_field); ?>`